# How to make a high resolution document in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, texmaker, preamble

I could finish my book and my publisher is requesting me to make it in high resolution.  I don't know what is she meaning because the book has a very good resolution.
This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[reqno,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}%Permite personalizar el índice alfabético
\makeindex[columns=2,options=-s AlgebraLineal.ist]%El archivo .ist contiene el estilo del guión corto
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{infwarerr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperheight=254.81mm,paperwidth=184.81mm,body={130mm,186mm},%Dimensiones papel y cuerpo del texto
            layoutoffset={7.405mm,7.405mm},%Distancia marcas de corte
            %showframe=true,
            layoutheight=240mm,%Altura del diseño de página
            layoutwidth=170mm,%Ancho del diseño de página
            %layoutvoffset=7mm,
            %layouthoffset=7mm,
            showcrop=true,%Muestra las marcas de corte
            centering]{geometry}%Centra el diseño en el papel usado
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx,psfrag,float}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelsep=space]{caption}%Configura el caption de las figuras
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}%Paquete para crear listas (enumerate, itemize) personalizadas
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}%"titles" permite cambiar tocloft con los comandos latex estándar para los títulos
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{apptools}
\usepackage{natbib}%Paquete para citaciones
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{tasks}%Paquete para hacer listas enumeradas horizontalmente
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

Please, focus on my problem.  I understand that my preamble maybe is a disaster but I don't have any time to correct it.   I just need how to make my book a high resolution document.

**NOTE 1:** in my book I used True Type Fonts because it was a requirement of my publisher.

**NOTE 2:** I'm compiling with XeLaTeX(x2)->seePDF and I'm working in TeXmaker.

How can I make my book a high resolution document using LaTeX?

Comment: If you do not tell us what high resolution means we cannot really help you. Have you checked that your images have a good image density or are vector graphics?

Comment: the fonts are scalable so not really at any resolution so the only issue should be the resolution of any bitmap jpg or png images

Comment: unrelated, but do not load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with xelatex (it does nothing other than make a warning telling you not to use it) and do not load `epsfig` for any document written after 1994, don't load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex (opentype fonts are not T1 encoded) don't load `enumerate` if you are loading `enumitem` (they can not both redefine the same `enumerate` enviornment.)

Comment: Actually, I don't have clar what is meaning my publisher.  I understand that fonts are scalables but I have several images converted from .jpg to .pdf.  I guess that that is the problem.  In that case I don't know to make them with a better resolution.

Comment: @Fabio, it depends on how you convert `.jpg` to `.pdf`. The resolution is what it is; you can try to upscale them (with GIMP of whatever) before converting. If you give more details, maybe we can help (state the pixel size of jpeg, the size of the final figure, and the method you use to convert).

Comment: from a printer perspective high-resolution would be anything above 300dpi. Pixel size and dpi are dependent, so you need to ask your publisher what minimum resolution any images need to be (e.g., what dpi) and then you need to make sure that the images have that dpi for the size you want to display them in your document. As said GIMP or photoshop can help you achieve that. Photos are typically binary images (e.g., jpeg, png, gif and so on) and when scaled lose quality, unlike vector images (e.g., wmf, emf, svg, which are typically line drawings).

Comment: My publisher finally told me what was the problem: the color images that have dotted lines becomes continuous line when they print them. They don't know why and so neither I.  The images were made by pstricks and then I edited them with **inkscape** (I had to add some text with special fonts) and saved them as **pdf**.  I'm going to try save them as **eps** files.  I really don't know why that behavior when they print the images.

Comment: @Fabio, so it was a problem with the printer and your problem is not related to latex?